# Requisição JSON: Erro cabeçalho CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, json

Preciso fazer uma requisição JSON para o PayU, mas me mostra a mensagem:

> Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same
>   Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em
>   https://sandbox.api.payulatam.com/payments-api/4.0/service.cgi?test=false&language=en&command=PING&merchant%5BapiLogin%5D=111111&merchant%5BapiKey%5D=22222222.
>   (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está
>   presente).

JS

```
    var data = {
        "test": false,
        "language": "en",
        "command": "PING",
        "merchant": {
            "apiLogin": "1111111",
            "apiKey": "22222222"
        }
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://sandbox.api.payulatam.com/payments-api/4.0/service.cgi",
        method: 'GET',
        dataType:'json',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('ok');

            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Tentei colocar o seguinte código no header, mas continua a mesma coisa:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
```

Já procurei outras perguntas semelhantes, mas nenhuma ajudou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creio que esse post abaixo poderá ajuda-lo

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114436/access-control-allow-origin-error-sending-a-jquery-post-to-google-apis

foi atribuido o `dataType: 'jsonp'`, obtendo sucesso dessa forma.